# django - tuple in a template only returning first character?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access a tuple in a django template but for some reason i am only seeing the first character, i thought it may be because using .# returns substrings, so i took the # off, upon which it returns nothing at all

context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings

def ProviderUrls(request):
    return {
    'circuit_providers': settings.PROVIDER_CHOICES,
    }
```

settings.py

```
#CONSTANTS

PROVIDER_CHOICES = (
        ('KCOM','KCOM'),
        ('BT','BT'),
        ('EE','EE'),
        ('THREE','THREE'),
        ('TALK TALK','TALK TALK'),
    )
```

template

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Management Menu</h3>

    <ul>
    {% for key, tuple in circuit_providers %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'management:provider' tuple.0 %}">{{ tuple.0 }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over `circuit_providers` this way:

```
{% for key, tuple in circuit_providers %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

You *unpack* every inner tuple, `key` is becoming `KCOM`, `tuple` is becoming `KCOM`, then `key` becomes `BT`, `tuple` becomes `BT` etc.

And when you do `{{ tuple.0 }}`, you are basically getting the first character in the string, which is `K` for `KCOM`.

To demonstrate that, see:

```
>>> for key, tuple in PROVIDER_CHOICES:
...     print(tuple)
... 
KCOM
BT
EE
THREE
TALK TALK
>>> for key, tuple in PROVIDER_CHOICES:
...     print(tuple[0])
... 
K
B
E
T
T
```

---

Instead, I think you meant to just do:

```
{% for key, tuple in circuit_providers %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'management:provider' tuple %}">{{ tuple }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```